# Fix JUnit - Autowire Clock

Tags: junit, dependency-injection, autowired, clock

I have a project that looks like the below,

[image]

The Clock is defined in a config file as

```java
    @Qualifier("helperClock")
    @Bean
    public Clock helperClock() {
        return Clock.systemDefaultZone();
    }
```

I need to write JUnit for 2 classes:

1) Test HelperClass1
My code - doesn't work

```java
    @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
    @SpringBootTest
    public class HelperClass1Test {
        @MockBean
        private Clock helperClock;
        @Autowired
        private HelperClass1 helperClass1;

        @Before
        public void init() {
            helperClock = Clock.fixed(Instant.parse("2017-12-03T10:15:30.00Z"), ZoneId.systemDefault());
        }

        @Test
        public void testSomeHelperMethod1() {
            helperClass1.someHelperMethod1(); // I WANT mocked helperClock to be injected into HelperClass1 and used.
        }
    }
```

2) Test the ImplClass - doesn't work

```java
    @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
    @SpringBootTest
    public class HelperClass1Test {
        @MockBean
        private Clock helperClock;
        @Autowired
        private SomeServiceImpl someServiceImpl;

        @Before
        public void init() {
            helperClock=Clock.fixed(Instant.parse("2017-12-03T10:15:30.00Z"),ZoneId.systemDefault());
        }   

        @Test
        public void testSomeServiceMethod() {
            someServiceImpl.SomeServiceMethod(); // I WANT mocked helperClock to be injected into HelperClass1 and used.
        }
    }
```

How do I fix this code?

Comment: 1)  Why is your *bean* labeled with a qualifier?  You typically use those to tell Spring which bean to wire *in*.  2)  Why are you mocking your beans?  Do you simply not care about their behavior in this context, or do you want more control over your injectables?

Comment: Hi Makoto, 1) I labelled my bean with @Qualifier because I was getting an error that the bean is not found otherwise. Strangely adding a qualifier fixed this problem. 2) I am mocking my beans because I want more control over the injectables. I want the Clock to always be fixed at '2017-03-12T10:15:30.00Z'

Answer (score 0):

I've often advocated the use of mocks before in a Spring context since it means that you can simply inject and substitute in the behavior your want in your tests.  However, I soon realized that this would turn out to be more of a mistake than I wanted it to be; mocking these things out was never a proof that the thing would work/wire correctly to begin with.

With that said, there are three things I would recommend you do.

1. Specify a profile for your tests to run under.  You can use "test" if you like.
2. Create beans which live underneath your test profile, and use those to inject in.
3. **Avoid using mocks.**  They are tempting and can be useful, but if you're planning on using Spring's injection capabilities, it's best to get away from them outright.

For starters, this is how I'd redefine the test class you have to use a specific `Clock` bean set at a specific time.  Take note of the following:

- I force the `Clock` bean to be primary, so it will be *the* authoritative `Clock` bean used in this test context.
- I force the profile to be "test" so that beans underneath that profile can be wired.
- I ensure that I add this bean to the context scan inside of the test, by adding the class entry to the `SpringBootTest` annotation.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = {
        YourSpringBootContextClassIfApplicable.class,
        HelperClass1Test.HelperClass1TestConfiguration.class
})
@ActiveProfiles("test")
public class HelperClass1Test {

    @Autowired
    private HelperClass1 helperClass1;

    @Test
    public void testSomeHelperMethod1() {
        helperClass1.someHelperMethod1();
    }

    @Configuration
    @Profile("test")
    static class HelperClass1TestConfiguration {

        @Bean
        @Primary
        public Clock helperClock() {
            return Clock.fixed(Instant.parse("2017-12-03T10:15:30.00Z"), ZoneId.systemDefault());
        }
    }
}
```